# org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Hi I am getting the above exception when i try for Selenium in windows, but not when I am 
   trying in Linux (CentO.S.).

```
Sample code is shown below :
```

```java
public class Simple {

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
String baseUrl;

    @Test
    public void f() {
        WebElement abc = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/"+
                      "tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/input"));
        abc.sendKeys("Jaivir");
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() {
        baseUrl ="http://localhost:8657/NutechDiagnostics/AcceptTest.jsp";
        driver.get(baseUrl);
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void afterTest() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}    

baseUrl given is completely accurate. Is it the problem of browser. Please help me i 
 am getting stuck here for a lot of time. Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: is Firefox installed in the Windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

From [Selenium classguide](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/UnreachableBrowserException.html):

> Indicates there was a problem communicating with the browser being controlled 
>   or the Selenium server. The most common causes for this exception are:
>
> - The provided server address to RemoteWebDriver is invalid, so the connection could not be established.
> - The browser has died mid-test.

So if it goes well in Linux but not in Windows, I would discard the second option. Probably your Windows version of Firefox is not well installed, or Selenium hasn't got permission to execute it.